# Insert and update with select in HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

**Insert with Select**

```
INSERT INTO FIN_COA_POSTED (DEBIT_AMOUNT,CREDIT_AMOUNT)
SELECT DEBIT_AMOUNT+__amount,CREDIT_AMOUNT FROM FIN_COA_POSTED WHERE  
ID =(SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM FIN_COA_POSTED WHERE FK_CHART_OF_ACCOUNT=5);
```

**Update with Select**

```
UPDATE fin_bank_account AS t1 JOIN 
(SELECT ID, BALANCE+__amount AS totalamount FROM fin_bank_account WHERE     
ID=7) 
AS t2 ON t1.id =t2.id 
SET  t1.balance =t2.totalamount;
```

**Note**

```
( IN __amount DOUBLE)
```

can we able to write corospondance HQL in hiberante ? update plz . thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to emulate an `INSERT ... SELECT` in HQL, you have two choices:

`Native SQL`: You can write a native SQL query (as you have done in your question)

`HQL`: In this case, you must define a POJO class named, for example, `FIN_COA_POSTED` and map it with your database.

So you can write an HQL select query to extract data, put this data in a `List<FIN_COA_POSTED>` and then you can save on your database your list.

About `UPDATE` statement, you can write a HQL query and then you can use executeUpdate() to perform your `UPDATE` statement.

If you want, you can [see here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/) about operations with Hibernate